# How to change Ag-grid date filter placeholder(format) using agDateColumnFilter

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, placeholder, datefilter

I am using agDateColumnFilter and want to change my date format in filter. It is also called placeholder. I want to change as dd/mm/yyyy but by default, i am getting dd-mm-yyyy. I didn't find anything through which i can understand that this placeholder can be changed. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I have tried placing placeholder in filterParams but it didn't help me.

```
jsonObj['filterParams'] = {comparator : RFADateFormatterService.customDateComparator, placeholder = 'dd/mm/yyyy'};
                jsonObj['filter'] =  'agDateColumnFilter' ;
```

I am expecting that should change in UI date filter but it is still showing dd-mm-yyyy in chrome.

Comment: jsonObj['filterParams'] = {comparator : RFADateFormatterService.customDateComparator, placecholder='dd/mm/yyyy'};
                jsonObj['filter'] =  'agDateColumnFilter' ;

Comment: you can use moment.js to convert your date input into different formates,, update the date to desire format then pass it to AgGrid... let me know if I am missing anything